# How to get previous selected value from another selection into current selection onclick?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have 3 selection. The jQuery onchange occur when user select the third selection and post the variable to another PHP file so I can check the database based on the id selected. The problem is, how I can get the first and second selection variable to post it together with the third selection?

These are tables I used:

```
    fromlist table : 
    | id | fromname |
    |  1 |     A    |
    |  2 |     B    |
    |  3 |     C    |

    tolist table:
    | id | toname |
    |  1 |    Z   |

    productlist table:
    | id | name |
    |  1 | CPO  |
    |  2 | PK   |

    transport table:
    | id  | product_id | product | to_id | from_id | price  |
    |  1  |     100    |    1    |   1   |    1    | 100.00 |
    |  2  |     101    |    2    |   1   |    1    | 200.00 |
    |  3  |     102    |    1    |   1   |    2    | 300.00 |
    |  4  |     103    |    2    |   1   |    2    | 400.00 |
    |  5  |     104    |    2    |   1   |    3    | 500.00 |
```

Here is the code:

```
<form name = "transport" method = "GET" action = "http://interlink2u.com/transport/transportfiles/verify.php">
        <select name = "phive_product_id" id = "phive_product_id" hidden></select>  

        <label>From:</label>
            <select name = "select_from" id = "select_from" required>
                <option id = "" value = "">None</option>
                <?php
                    $fromlist = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM fromlist ORDER BY fromname ASC");

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fromlist))
                    {
                        $getID = $row['id'];
                        $getName = $row['fromname'];
                        ?><option id = "<?php echo $getID; ?>" value = "<?php echo $getName; ?>"><?php echo $getName;?></option><?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select><br><br>

        <label>To:</label>
            <select name = "select_to" id = "select_to" required>
                <option id = "" value = "">None</option>
                <?php
                    $tolist = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM tolist ORDER BY toname ASC");

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tolist))
                    {
                        $getID = $row['id'];
                        $getName = $row['toname'];
                        ?><option id = "<?php echo $getID; ?>" value = "<?php echo $getName; ?>"><?php echo $getName;?></option><?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <br><br>

        <label>Product:</label>
            <select name = "select_product" id = "select_product" required>
                <option id = "" value = "">None</option>
                <?php
                    $products = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY name ASC");

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($products))
                    {
                        $getID = $row['id'];
                        $getName = $row['name'];
                        ?><option id = "<?php echo $getID; ?>" value = "<?php echo $getName; ?>"><?php echo $getName;?></option><?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>

            <select name = "phive_booked_price" id = "phive_booked_price" hidden></select>
            <br><br>

        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit" id="disablebutton">
</form><br><br><br>
```

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", 'select#select_product', function(e) 
        {
            var productID = jQuery(this).children(":selected").attr("id");
            var fromID = jQuery('#select_from').children(":selected").attr("id");
            var toID = jQuery('#select_to').children(":selected").attr("id");

            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                data: {productID: productID, fromID: fromID, toID: toID},
                url: 'http://interlink2u.com/transport/transportfiles/getprice.php',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json) 
                {
                    var $el4 = jQuery("select#phive_product_id");
                    $el4.empty();
                    $.each(json, function(k, v) 
                    {                     
                        $el4.append("<option id = '" + v.product_id + "'value = '" + v.product_id + "'>" + v.product_id + "</option>");
                    });

                    var $el5 = jQuery("select#phive_booked_price");
                    $el5.empty();                        
                    $.each(json, function(k, v) 
                    {    
                        $el5.append("<option id = '" + v.product_id + "'value = '" + v.price + "'>" + v.price + "</option>");
                    });
                }
            });                
        })
```

getprice.php code:

```
<?php 
    include_once 'config/config.php';

    $productID= $_POST['productID'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM transport 
                                            INNER JOIN tolist ON transport.to_name = tolist.id
                                            INNER JOIN products ON transport.product = products.id 
                                            WHERE product = '" .$productID. "'");
    $results = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

I want to get the first and second selected values and post it to getprice.php so I can query the result like this:

```
<?php 
    include_once 'config/config.php';

    $fromID = $_POST['fromID'];
    $toID = $_POST['toID'];
    $productID = $_POST['productID'];

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM transport 
                                            INNER JOIN tolist ON transport.to_name = tolist.id
                                            INNER JOIN products ON transport.product = products.id
                                            WHERE from_id = '" .$fromID. "'
                                            AND to_name = '".$toID."'
                                            AND product = '".$productID."'");
    $results = [];

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only sending productID in your ajax:

```
data: {productID: productID},
```

If you change your line to:

```
data: $('form[name="transport"]').serialize(),
```

[Read more on serialize.](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) Your jquery call will now look like:

```
jQuery(document).on("click", 'select#select_product', function(e) 
    {
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            data: $('form[name="transport"]').serialize(),
            url: 'http://interlink2u.com/transport/transportfiles/getprice.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) 
            {
                var $el4 = jQuery("select#phive_product_id");
                $el4.empty();
                $.each(json, function(k, v) 
                {                     
                    $el4.append("<option id = '" + v.product_id + "'value = '" + v.product_id + "'>" + v.product_id + "</option>");
                });

                var $el5 = jQuery("select#phive_booked_price");
                $el5.empty();                        
                $.each(json, function(k, v) 
                {    
                    $el5.append("<option id = '" + v.product_id + "'value = '" + v.price + "'>" + v.price + "</option>");
                });
            }
        });                
    })
```

Then in your getprice.php code you would need to update:

```
$productID = $_POST['select_product']; // now select_product as per your selectbox name
```

But you also now have available:

```
$_POST['select_from']
$_POST['select_to']
$_POST['phive_booked_price']
$_POST['phive_product_id']
```

EDIT:

To include them the way you asked in the comments you would need to update:

```
var productID = $('#select_product').val();
var fromID = $('#select_from').val();
var toID= $('#select_to').val();
```

Comment: I still don't get it right. Is it possible to add more variable from the outside selection to `data: {productID: productID},` ?

Comment: for example `data: {productID: productID, fromID: fromID, toID: toID},` something like this

Comment: Updated my anwer, check the bottom, it is possible

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found the solution myself. It's working now. I have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you are sending data like this : `data: {productID: productID, fromID: fromID, toID: toID},`

so, in getprice.php, you should receive those like this:

```
 $fromID = $_POST['fromID'];
 $toID = $_POST['toID'];
 $productID = $_POST['productID'];
```

Comment: I have already try that but still not displaying the price and product id from the query. From the information in wordpress, sometimes this `"$"` symbol must change to `"jQuery"` in script but I also have tried that. Nothing seems to work. Is there anyway to monitor how the variable passes?

Comment: I have tried this `var productID = jQuery(this).children(":selected").attr("id");` in the script. It works but productID is in the third selection. So how to get the id of the first and second option since both selection were outside from the third selection script so that I can post all 3 selection in one go instead of one by one ?

Comment: you can print the data in console to check whether they are passing or not. for this, in getprice.php, write: `echo json_encode(array("fromID "=>$fromID ,"toID "=>$toID ,"productID "=>$productID ));` And then in ajax success function, write: `console.log(json.fromID );console.log(json.toID);console.log(json.productID );` If values pass successfully, you can see these values in browser console. Its for checking only

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have found the solution myself. It's working now. I have updated the code.